Bootstrap treeview node selected should remain same after page reload
I want treeview selection should remain same after page reload. I have tried the below code but it's not working anyone help me resolve this.
Tree.prototype.setSelectedState = function (node, state, options) {

        **localStorage.setItem('selectedNode', JSON.stringify(node.nodeId));**
        if (state === node.state.selected) return;

        if (state) {

            // If multiSelect false, unselect previously selected
            if (!this.options.multiSelect) {
                $.each(this.findNodes('true', 'g', 'state.selected'), $.proxy(function (index, node) {
                    this.setSelectedState(node, false, options);
                }, this));
            }

            // Continue selecting node
            node.state.selected = true;
            if (!options.silent) {
                this.$element.trigger('nodeSelected', $.extend(true, {}, node));
            }
        }
        else {

            // Unselect node
            node.state.selected = false;
            if (!options.silent) {
                this.$element.trigger('nodeUnselected', $.extend(true, {}, node));
            }
        }
    };

// Restore selection after page reload
$(document).ready(function() {
// Get the stored node ID from localStorage
var selectedNodeId = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('selectedNode'));
if (selectedNodeId !== null) {
    // Get the treeview instance
    var treeData = $('#STRUCTURE_BUILDER_left').treeview('getTree'); // Assuming you can access the tree data

    // Use the helper function to find the node by nodeId
    var node = findNodeById(treeData, selectedNodeId);

    if (node) {
        // Manually select the node
        $('#STRUCTURE_BUILDER_left').treeview('setSelectedState', node, true);
    }
}

});
// Helper function to find a node by its nodeId
function findNodeById(tree, nodeId) {
    let result = null;

    // Recursively search the tree
    function search(nodes) {
        $.each(nodes, function(index, node) {
            if (node.nodeId == nodeId) {
                result = node;
                return false; // Break the loop
            }
            if (node.nodes) {
                search(node.nodes); // Recursive search
            }
        });
    }

    search(tree);
    return result;
}



 var defaultData = [
        {
            text: 'Parent 1',
            href: '#parent1',
            tags: ['4'],
            nodes: [
                {
                    text: 'Child 1',
                    href: '#child1',
                    tags: ['2'],
                    nodes: [
                        {
                            text: 'Grandchild 1',
                            href: '#grandchild1',
                            tags: ['0']
                        },
                        {
                            text: 'Grandchild 2',
                            href: '#grandchild2',
                            tags: ['0']
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    text: 'Child 2',
                    href: '#child2',
                    tags: ['0']
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            text: 'Parent 2',
            href: '#parent2',
            tags: ['0']
        },
        {
            text: 'Parent 3',
            href: '#parent3',
            tags: ['0']
        },
        {
            text: 'Parent 4',
            href: '#parent4',
            tags: ['0']
        },
        {
            text: 'Parent 5',
            href: '#parent5'  ,
            tags: ['0']
        }
    ];

$('#treeview1').treeview({
    data: defaultData,
    collapseIcon:'fas fa-minus',
    expandIcon:'fas fa-plus'
 });
        .treeview .list-group-item {
            cursor: pointer
        }

        .treeview span.indent {
            margin-left: 10px;
            margin-right: 10px
        }

        .treeview span.icon {
            width: 12px;
            margin-right: 5px
        }

        .treeview .node-disabled {
            color: silver;
            cursor: not-allowed
        }

        .node-treeview1 {
        }

        .node-treeview1:not(.node-disabled):hover {
                background-color: #F5F5F5;
        }
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-treeview/1.2.0/bootstrap-treeview.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@3.4.1/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="treeview1" class="treeview">
<!--             <ul class="list-group">
                <li class="list-group-item node-treeview1" data-nodeid="0"
                    style="color:undefined;background-color:undefined;"><span
                        class="icon expand-icon glyphicon glyphicon-minus"></span><span class="icon node-icon"></span>Parent
                    1
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item node-treeview1" data-nodeid="1"
                    style="color:undefined;background-color:undefined;"><span class="indent"></span><span
                        class="icon expand-icon glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span><span class="icon node-icon"></span>Child
                    1
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item node-treeview1" data-nodeid="4"
                    style="color:undefined;background-color:undefined;"><span class="indent"></span><span
                        class="icon glyphicon"></span><span class="icon node-icon"></span>Child 2
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item node-treeview1" data-nodeid="5"
                    style="color:undefined;background-color:undefined;"><span class="icon glyphicon"></span><span
                        class="icon node-icon"></span>Parent 2
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item node-treeview1" data-nodeid="6"
                    style="color:undefined;background-color:undefined;"><span class="icon glyphicon"></span><span
                        class="icon node-icon"></span>Parent 3
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item node-treeview1" data-nodeid="7"
                    style="color:undefined;background-color:undefined;"><span class="icon glyphicon"></span><span
                        class="icon node-icon"></span>Parent 4
                </li>
                <li class="list-group-item node-treeview1" data-nodeid="8"
                    style="color:undefined;background-color:undefined;"><span class="icon glyphicon"></span><span
                        class="icon node-icon"></span>Parent 5
                </li>
            </ul> -->
        </div>



